Retrieve Custom Metadata from SharePoint for all the Content Types using Microsoft Graph
I am using graph API query to get custom metadata for a file inside my sharepoint library folder path. The API query looks like this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{relative_folder_path}/{file_name}:/listItem?$expand=fields&$select=fields

Although this returns me all the metadata for that file but only for the default applied content type. There are multiple content types in my sharepoint library, and I want to get all the metadata for all the content types for the given file inside the path.
eg: If my drive has content types 'abc' with columns '1. bghh 2. ghhye' and 'def' with columns '1.yuh 2. 67gdt'; I would like to get all the columns metadata 'bghh,ghhye,yuh,67gdt' for that specific file inside the path.
How can I achieve that using Microsoft graph explorer ?
